# closing the database slows down the listview addition in C#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I use MS access as my database. I have 20 different set of buttons with specific id which fetches the data whenever the button is clicked.

I have created a separate function to fetch for the item name from the database with reference to id of the button.

The data will be added to the ListView.

It works pretty well.
But whenever I click on multiple buttons as fast as i can, the job becomes really slow (this is the case when I've applied database Open and Close in the item fetching function).

As I remove the database connection close function the job becomes really easy and too fast to add in the listview. But the problem is that it sometime conflicts with database open. Showing unrecognized error in database.Open(); function.

Any idea will be appreciated.

I am using C#.net visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening and closing connection is always very expensive but this is usually taken care of by the provider who behind the scene opens and hangs on to the connections for you.

However, as I read once, the connection pooling kicks in only when one connection is kept open (now this could depend on provider).

if your app will be used by only by a handful of people, opening the connection and using it everywhere in your app can be a better option.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info.